# Selenium - Unable to click a button inside a google page

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a problem clicking a button inside a google page.

My script is unable to click the button on the page.

It's kind of page which we normally get while installing any App.

This particular button is not in frame.

The button appears on page with delay of seconds, I had also tried with Implicit & WebDriver wait.

I tried lot of stuff without any success.

I have mentioned the things i tried & the Output which i got.

I would really appreciate if someone helps me on with this.

Things which i tried

1) Tried accessing the object with Id, Xpath

`d1.findElement(By.id("submit_approve_access")).click();`

or

`d1.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='submit_approve_access']")).click();`

Output - Nothing happens. Once i click the button(Allow Access) the script moves on smoothly

2) Tried Clicking the object with Javascript

`js.executeScript("document.getElementById('submit_approve_access').click()");`

or

`js.executeScript("window.document.getElementById('submit_access').click()");`

In IE's console i used following which clicked the button

`document.getElementById('submit_approve_access').click();`

Output - Same as Step 1

3) Tried by checking the Target path in IDE, took CSS & tried the following

`new WebDriverWait(d1,10000).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("css=#submit_approve_access"))).click();`

Also tried playing the recorded script but that script too stuck on the same page

Output - This time i got the following exception

`WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.selector: css=#submit_approve_access)
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'css=#submit_approve_access' is not a valid selector.
  (Session info: chrome=33.0.1750.146)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.6.232923,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 23 milliseconds`

4) Tried by doing above example with following

`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("submit_approve_access")));
     WebElement CLICK = d1.findElement(By.id("submit_approve_access"));
     CLICK.click();
   System.out.println("Element Found");`

Output: This time i had syso after the above code. So during my excution it did print Element Found. However, it didnt click the button

Comment: Did it throw an error on #4?  What happens if you wait until the element is visible and then click it with javascript?

Comment: @MrTi It did not error out. Control reached till syso though. I had put following this time WebDriverWait test = new WebDriverWait(d1, 15000); test.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("submit_approve_access")));                                     WebElement CLICK = d1.findElement(By.id("submit_approve_access"));
CLICK.click();  js.executeScript("document.getElementById('submit_approve_access').click()");
System.out.println("Element Found");

Comment: If the click doesn't work, then I'm guessing the javascript that runs when you press the button isn't attached to the element you are finding.  Is there an `input` element nearby? Maybe an `a` element?

Comment: @MrTi I used same line in IE console to verify if it clicks the button & it worked like charm there. js.executeScript("document.getElementById('submit_approve_access').click()"); Here is the screenshot http://www.screencast.com/t/Dg2Ubr5h

Comment: Hm.  Out of curiosity, run the script in debug mode, and have a break point right before the click.  The run the script line by line.  If that works, then you are running into a waiting issue, otherwise, I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: MrTi & @Saran, issue got resolved. I used the following & it worked fine.                                                       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d1, 20);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("submit_approve_access")));
element.click();                                                 Thank you very much for your help. Appreciate it very much. Thanks, Amar

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait` class. When it is looking for an element, this will poll until the expected condition is true and returns that condition's result. You can read about it [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).

Comment: The OP is using WebDriverWait in example 4.

Comment: @Saran, i tried the following WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(d1, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("submit_approve_access"))); System.out.println("Clicking Element"); myDynamicElement.click(); System.out.println("Element Clicked");In the first run i gave invalid id to verify presenceofelementlocated,so ii just waited,did nothing & did not print 'Element found'.In the next run i passed valid id & it printed Element Found.I inserted myDynamicElement.click(); in next run, it printed element found but didn't click the button